# Патрикей и Патрик

Tags: имена-собственные

Святой Патрик, оказывается, почитается и Православной церковью. А имени Патрик в русском языке нет. И мне стало интересно: чей тогда покровитель святой Патрик? Патрикея? Это одно и то же имя или разные?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это разный вариант одного и того же имени. Патрикий от ирл.Naomh Pádraig.Подробнее здесь:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%E2%FF%F2%EE%E9_%CF%E0%F2%F0%E8%EA